# Какой конкретно поток ставит на паузу метод "Thread.sleep()"?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Создаю поток следующим образом:

```
public class Program        //Класс с методом main().
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Создание потока
        Thread myThready = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() //Этот метод будет выполняться в побочном потоке
            {
                System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
                Thread.sleep(200);// пауза текущего потока или главного?
                // чем тогда отличается от Thread.currentThread().sleep(200); ?
            }
        });
        myThready.start();  //Запуск потока

        System.out.println("Главный поток завершён...");
    }
}
```

Метод  `Thread.sleep(200)` какой конкретно поток  ставит на паузу? Чем тогда это отличается от `Thread.currentThread().sleep(200)` ?

Comment: на всякий случай, `sleep` - статический метод. Ява допускает запись `ссылка.статический_метод()`, но вызванный метод определяется типом выражения слева от точки на этапе компиляции в байт-код. Можно написать `new Thread().sleep(1)` или `((Thread)null).sleep(1)`, результат будет один. IDE обычно предупреждают. По существу вопроса, "качество сна" разными методами [зависит от реализации и операционной системы](https://dzone.com/articles/yield-sleep0-wait01-and) и иногда [настраивается](https://blog.hazelcast.com/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/). Тестируйте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep(200)
```

действует на поток, в котором выполняется эта инструкция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(200)
```

делает то же самое, посредством ссылки на экземпляр потока, не надо так делать так как это вызов статического метода из у экземпляра класса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]